# How to read different field value during SchemaMapping in GraphQL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

I have scenario as follows:
Trying to read different data model value during schema mapping.

My question is how to pass "isbn" (**ISBN is under Book model**) into mapping method when perform schema mapping in GraphQL ?

```
type Book {
  id: ID
  isbn: String
  name: String
  pageCount: Int
  authorList: [Author]
}

type Author {
  id: ID
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  address: [Address]
}

type Address {
  id: ID
  street: String
  city: String
  country: String
  countryCode: String
}
```

Mapping method:

```
@SchemaMapping
public String countryCode(Address address) {
  return  xService.getIsbnCountryCode(isbn,address);
}
```